# Use of Models in asp.net MVC for API integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using 3rd party API to get and manipulate data used for my asp.net mvc application. Since I am beginner in MVC, from my standpoint I believe that use of models component of MVC pattern in such cases is not really needed. Only need to use models in this case would be if I would like to additionally manipulate data pulled from API.

Could someone please clarify if I am missing sometime in my theory.

Comment: Models in MVC aren't just your entities nor just business logic. A model is pretty much the core of your app..

Comment: @walther when you say core of the application, so far I see a need for models only when using it with forms. am i missing something?

Comment: Model = all your entities, db access, business logic etc. Pretty much everything that isn't tied to the UI actually is a model. Model is ignorant to how it's used or where. You should be able to re-use the model and create a desktop application with it without any changes. If you'd work with WPF, we use a pattern called MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel, notice the Model here).

Comment: @walther after checking more on MVVM, for me it is difficult now not to use this pattern! thanks provide this in form of an answer so I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with you on your theory. It might seem a bit overkill to create a set of classes when retrieving data form a 3rd party application. In the beginning it may seem like a lot of unnecessary work.

However, my personal opinion is to always map classes in the MVC application. My reason for doing this is to keep as clear as possible separation of concern in my applications. If you need a similar application in the future or you are changing back-end for some reason, the MVC/front-end application will be as independent as possible.

It is also nice to keep a clear separation of concern if you are working with other developers and if the application will be used for an extended period of time. Also imagine if you would like to do some manipulation of the data, like you say in your own words.

To summarise, I think it is good practice to always keep a model class in your MVC application.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but from all the examples and books I have checked, models are pretty much always used with forms. and that makes sense to use models in app to make it clean and easy to use. but for displaying static data in html, is there really a need for models?

Comment: I can just assume how the 3rd party API you are works. Assuming it returns JSON data, I agree with walter, MVVM is your best option.  Model is used to distinguish your own domain from the 3rd party. The 3rd party only gives you data. Your application is your domain, your business logic and interpretation of the data.